# how to un-check read only in field properties - page layout

Tags: page-layout

How to un-check read only from page layout (field properties)? please see the screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you can't uncheck the read-only property, that means that the field itself is read-only. For example, formula fields and rollup summary fields are read-only, because they are managed by the system. Other fields are read-only because they are system properties, such as the audit fields (under normal situations). You'll also find fields which have the opposite status as well. They are required, and cannot be removed from a page or made optional.

Comment: Understood. But why it is not visible on the page layout? I have checked the field level security and it's checked on visible.

Comment: Can you share screenshot of your page layout ? Are there any Record types which may interfere with page layout ?

Comment: Sort of a different question...

Comment: @AbuHamzah Technically, it is a different question (and I'm not specifically familiar with the field in the OP, but this answer applies globally), but some fields only show themselves in certain cases, such as Lead Campaign (only on new leads, not editing existing leads). You could probably find out more by checking the Help & Training documentation, although not all fields are clearly documented.